# convert nanosecond value into datetime using pyspark in databricks

Tags: python, azure-databricks, python-datetime, pyspark-pandas

I'm trying to recreate some work I have already done in Python using Databricks.  I have a dataframe and within it is a column called 'time', of data in nanoseconds.  In Python, I use the following code to convert the field into the appropriate datetime values:

```
import pandas as pd

# Convert time field from nanoseconds into datetime
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"], unit='ns')
```

This code converts the following value 1642778070000000000 into 2022-01-21 15:14:30.  I now want to do this in databricks using pyspark (as I'm scaling up the problem and the dataset I'm using is too large to do in Python).  I've created a spark dataframe called df and then imported the pyspark.pandas functions and then tried effectively the same code, but it doesn't work:

```
from pyspark import pandas as ps
df = df.ps.to_datetime(df.columns[2], unit='ns') #the time column is in column index 2
```

I get an error:

'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ps'

Any suggestions?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyspark does not provide any direct functions to work with time in nanoseconds. There is a function called `from_unixtime()` which takes time in **seconds** as argument and converts it to a timestamp of the format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` (your requirement). So, to use this function we must manually convert these nanoseconds to seconds using Pyspark.

The following is the demonstration of code that I have used on my sample data:

- The following is the schema and sample data in my dataframe `df`.

[image]

- To convet nanoseconds to seconds, use the following code.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = df.withColumn("seconds", (col('nanoseconds')/1000000000)) 
df.show() 

+---+-------------------+--------------------+
| id|        nanoseconds|             seconds|
+---+-------------------+--------------------+
|  1|1642778070000000000|        1.64277807E9|
|  2|1360287003083912345|1.3602870030839124E9|
+---+-------------------+--------------------+
```

- Now we have `seconds` column which is of type double. Now you can use `from_unixtime()` and pass the `seconds` column as an argument as shown below.

```
df = df.withColumn("date_time",from_unixtime(col('seconds'))) 
df.show() 

+---+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| id|        nanoseconds|             seconds|          date_time|
+---+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|  1|1642778070000000000|        1.64277807E9|2022-01-21 15:14:30|
|  2|1360287003083912345|1.3602870030839124E9|2013-02-08 01:30:03|
+---+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

[image]

Now you have a `date_time` column of `StringType` which contains the values of the respective nanoseconds as timestamp in the format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer - really detailed and helpful.  It works perfectly.  Thanks!